# struct with const member

Tags: c++, struct, constants

I'm having some trouble with a template struct.

```
template<typename T>
struct A{
    const int v1;
    T* v2;
};
```

My purpose is to make `v1` always not editable, while `v2` should be editable if I use `T` and not editable if I use `const T` as type.

If I create constructor to initialize `A`, the struct becomes:

```
template<typename T>
struct A{
    const int v1;
    T* v2;
    A() : v1(-1) { v2=NULL; }
    A(int value) : v1(value) { v2=NULL; }
};
```

But then g++ says that I need a specific assignment operator:

> error: non-static const member ‘const int A::v1’, can’t use default assignment operator

But my assignment operator should also allow editing of `v1`. The only thing I'd like to avoid is an edit from the outside, something like:

```
A a;
a.v1=10;
```

Is there any way to implement this (without creating getter/setter or using a pointer to a new A(int) with the desired value)?

What if I declare v1 as a const int * ? It could refer someway to some value, but it cannot edit it.

Comment: "without converting struct to class (...)" What you have is already a class.

Comment: You have to understand that in C++ a struct IS a class, just a very specific type of class. A struct is a class where everything is public.

Comment: If the assignment operator is able to modify `const` members then you still have the problem of *edit from the outside* because I can just perform an assignment of the whole object instead of modifying `obj.v1` by itself

Comment: Why exactly do you not want to add getter/setters, by the way?

Comment: `const mutable` would've come in very handy :-)

Comment: @Poodlehat because A has to be a struct, so I cannot use private data.

Comment: What if I remove the constructors and declare v1 as const int*, then I could change the address v1 points to, but not the value of the pointed value.

Comment: @Poodlehat: "A struct is a class where everything is public". No, a struct is a class where members and bases are public by default. Structs can still have private members. It basically doesn't matter which you use of `struct` and `class`, as long as you're consistent all it affects is where you need to type access specifiers. It can also affect how the name is mangled.

Comment: "My purpose is to make v1 always not editable" ... "my assignment operator should also allow editing of v1" -- there's your problem, directly contradicting requirements. Pick one of them to give up.

Comment: @SteveJessop I'm thinking to declare v1 as const int* , so that I can change v1 address (and the value v1 points to), but I can't edit it.

Comment: @Vektor88: but then whoever it is you were trying to prevent from changing the value of `v1` when it was a `const int`, can change the pointer value now that it's a `const int *`. Plus you have the question of how the `int`s are allocated and freed. There is no good way to allow the copy assignment operator to change the value, while preventing other member functions from changing it. Neither is there a good way to expose a non-const member to the public in a way that prevents them from writing it. C++ doesn't have that fine-grained encapsulation built in, you have to roll your own.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7522/discussion-between-vektor88-and-steve-jessop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to "expose" a public, read-only data member that is modifiable by the class's own member functions (including assignment):

```
template <typename T>
class Helper {
    friend class A;
    T *ptr;
    Helper &operator=(const Helper &rhs) = default; // in C++11
    Helper &operator=(const Helper &rhs) { ptr = rhs.ptr; } // in C++03
  public:
    Helper(T *ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
    operator const int &() const { return *ptr; }
};

class A {
    int v1_;
  public:
    Helper<int> v1;
    A() : v1(&v1_) {} // although `A` should have a constructor that sets `v1_`
    A(const A &rhs) { v1_ = rhs.v1_; v1 = Helper<int>(&v1_); }
    A &operator=(const A &rhs) { v1_ = rhs.v1_; v1 = Helper<int>(&v1_); }
};
```

Now anyone outside the class A can use `v1`, but the only thing they can use it for is to get a `const int&` reference to `v1_`.

It is far easier just to give `A` a getter function that returns `const int &`, but if you really want the data member syntax then this provides it...

Comment: Looks better than my solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It says that you cannot use the *default* assignment operator. Nothing keeps you from writing your own `operator=` and use a `const_cast`. Unfortunately, this will be undefined behavior as `v1` is declared const. So I'd suggest that you use accessors and private data.

Comment: Is it still undefined behavior if you use `const_cast`?

Comment: @PaulManta The standard is quite clear here: `const_cast` results in undefined behaviour iff the object has been **declared** `const`. This is the case for the member variable. I can dig up the quotes, if it makes you feel better.

Comment: Oh, I see. Good think you put emphasis on "declared", I wouldn't have noticed it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make it a class with everything public (thats all a struct is) and use an initialisation list - no need for getters/setters

Comment: @pmr - Correct, but if it's a const I would really prefer to set it at ctor time anyway. Your solution is better for his question

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing the type of v1 from int to const int *, by doing this I can change the address of v1 and consequently change the value that v1 points to, but preventing any kind of editing.

So, here's my new simple struct

```
template<typename T>
struct A{
    const int* v1;
    T* v2;
};
```

When I use A with type T, I let v2 to be edited, and when I use A with type T const I prevent any attempt to edit v2's pointed value.